# Javascript Alert in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback, alert

I want to use [Javascript Alert](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert) function in my ASP.NET page.

For example like this;

```
Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('ERROR');</script>);
```

But, this doesn't work.

I ask in here what am i doing wrong and everyone suggest me using [RegisterScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), " ", "alert('ERROR')",true);
```

But i don't want use it because it's working with `PostBack`

How can i do that without `PostBack`?

EDIT: For example for using;

```
try
{
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    myConnection.Open();

    string hesap = Label1.Text;
    string musteriadi = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    string avukat = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AVUKAT VALUES (@MUSTERI, @AVUKAT, @HESAP)", myConnection);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HESAP", hesap);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MUSTERI", musteriadi);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVUKAT", avukat);
    cmd.Connection = myConnection;

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Response.Write("<h2>ERROR</h2>");
}
```

Comment: what are you really trying to do? **Client validation**? there are much better methods. **Server validation**? you normally send the error message back to your view / aspx page and show it

Comment: What do you mean by "without postback"? What should trigger the alert box?

Comment: Server validation. I want to use it with my database connection try-catch blocke..

Comment: But if you want to do server validation, you need to run code on the *server*, right? That means you have to transfer control back to the server, i.e. you need either a *postback* (which you apparently don't want to use) or AJAX. Do you use AJAX?

Comment: @Heinzi I update my question. Please look at.

Comment: @Soner: Thanks. That's not the relevant part, however: It's not important how you do your database access, it's important where you run the code that should raise the alert. Is it during Form_Load? Is it the codebehind of a button click? Does the button click cause a full postback or a partial one (i.e. do you use UpdatePanels)? Do you use AJAX (if yes, how)?

Comment: @Heinzi It is during Button_Click(). No and no. I just using a button and test the connection is right or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [a note from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338357.aspx):

> If you want to register a script block
>   that does not pertain to partial-page
>   updates, and if you want to register
>   the script block only one time during
>   initial page rendering, use the
>   `RegisterClientScriptBlock` method of
>   the `ClientScriptManager` class. You can
>   get a reference to the
>   `ClientScriptManager` object from the
>   `ClientScript` property of the page.

So, I think [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx) method is what you need:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    this.GetType(), 
    " ", 
    @"<script language=javascript>alert('ERROR');</script>", 
    true
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you forgot the quotation mark. I just tried it in a sample page like this:

```
Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('ERROR');</script>");
```

and it worked. Where did you place the Response.Write in your code? Could you give some more details? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

For displaying an alert message to the User, in a webpage i have a code have a look at this

```
public void UserMsgBox(string sMsg)
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
System.Web.UI.Control oFormObject = null;
sMsg = sMsg.Replace("'", "\\'");
sMsg = sMsg.Replace(Strings.Chr(34), "\\" + Strings.Chr(34));
sMsg = sMsg.Replace(Constants.vbCrLf, "\\n");
sMsg = "<script language='javascript'>alert(\"" + sMsg + "\")</script>";
sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(sMsg);
foreach (System.Web.UI.Control oFormObject_loopVariable in this.Controls) {
    oFormObject = oFormObject_loopVariable;
    if (oFormObject is HtmlForm) {
        break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
    }
}
oFormObject.Controls.AddAt(oFormObject.Controls.Count, new LiteralControl(sb.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using RegisterStartupscript for registering the script.
Refer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx